# Drupal - drupal_add_js not working

Tags: javascript, php, drupal

I've added this to the top of my `template.php` file in my theme,

However my page `page--front.tpl.php` is not receiving the javascript that is within the map.js file.

Am I incorrectly using this function?? Thanks for all and any help!!

Current Code:

```
function creative_responsive_theme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
    if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'creative_responsive_theme') . '/js/map.js');
    }
}
```

Also, when I inspect element, this is what I get in my console in regards to the `.js` file

[image]

Comment: Try to add the javascript from a module

Answer (score 0):

Every thing looks fine for me. But there're few things to try:

1- Make sure to flush the caches (theme registry cache at least) after adding `creative_responsive_theme_preprocess_html` to your `template.php file.

2- I never used `drupal_is_front_page`, so I can't judge how it works. An easier way to check if the page is front page is by checking the `is_front` value inside `$variables` array

```
function creative_responsive_theme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

    if ($variables['is_front']) { // THE EDITED LINE.
        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'creative_responsive_theme') . '/js/map.js');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your response! I tried out your code but unfortunately it didn't solve my issue. My `page--front.tpl.php` is definitely working, as I can see the divs that I've created in the `page--front.tpl.php`, however the .js file i've created is not being run

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly, I name my front page template `page--front.tpl.php`. Maybe your function `drupal_is_front_page()` doesn't work because of that.

Comment: What's funny is that my front page template is named that, but some guy edited my question and changed that for no apparent reason

Comment: Mh ok! Sorry! Have you check if a "<" is not where is not supposed to be? It may b somewhere in your HTML.